# List based on variable from two tables

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

My program is a task program of sorts. What I'd like to do is construct a UI for a user/employee to see tasks they have to do on the given day the log in.

I have two tables, PostOne and PostEig, in a 1-M.

- PostOne is the master table that contains the information about a single task.
- PostEig is a table of users that are assigned to a task in Post One.

The models [simplified]

```
public class PostOne
{
    public string One { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string Two { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime ThrD { get; set; }
}

public class PostEig
{
    public string EigOne { get; set; }
    public string EigTwo { get; set; } //foreign key
    [Key]
    public string EigID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string EigA { get; set; }  //user login 
}
```

I'm having trouble with the controller. I'm not even sure how to start on the code necessary to achieve my goal, so I'm going to try to write it out:

1. call a list of PostEigs Where EigA == User.Identity.Name
2. and from this list.. call a list of PostOnes Where Two == EigTwo
3. and from this list.. call a list of PostOnes Where ThrD == DateTime.UtcNow.Date

I did try something like this:

```
public ActionResult SkedList()
{
    return View(db.PostEigs.Where(m =>
            m.EigA == User.Identity.Name ||
            m.EigTwo == db.PostOnes.Where(o => o.ThrD == DateTime.UtcNow.Date)
            ).ToList());
}
```

If this is unclear, please let me know. I appreciate any advice or solutions, even if in a different direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like this is a candidate for an [`Inner Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397941.aspx). I find it's much easier to think in terms of SQL then transform it into LINQ.

### SQL Query:

```
SELECT 
    po.* 
FROM 
    PostOnes po
INNER JOIN 
    PostEig pe
ON 
    pe.EigTwo = po.Two
WHERE 
    pe.EigA = AUTH_NAME AND po.ThrD = TODAY()
```

### C# LINQ Query:

```
var DB_PostEig = new List<PostEig>()
{
    new PostEig(){EigTwo = "Foo1", EigA =  "Foo"},
    new PostEig(){EigTwo = "Foo2", EigA =  "Foo"},
    new PostEig(){EigTwo = "Bar1", EigA =  "Bar"},
    new PostEig(){EigTwo = "Bar2", EigA =  "Bar"}
};

var DB_PostOnes = new List<PostOne>()
{
    new PostOne(){Two = "Foo1", ThrD = new DateTime(1900,1,1)},
    new PostOne(){Two = "Foo2", ThrD = new DateTime(2000,1,1)},
    new PostOne(){Two = "Foo3", ThrD = new DateTime(1900,1,1)},
    new PostOne(){Two = "Bar1", ThrD = new DateTime(1900,1,1)},
    new PostOne(){Two = "Bar2", ThrD = new DateTime(1900,1,1)}
};

var authName = "Foo";
var currentDate = new DateTime(1900,1,1);

//Not sure if this is the most optimal LINQ Query, but it seems to work.
var queryReturn = DB_PostOnes.Join(DB_PostEig.Where(x => x.EigA == authName), x => x.Two, y => y.EigTwo, (x, y) => x)
    .Where(z => z.ThrD == currentDate)
    .ToList();

queryReturn.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Two + " - " + x.ThrD)); //Foo1 - 1/1/1900
```

#### Edit:

### LINQ Query without a join

```
var queryTwo = DB_PostOnes
    .Where(x => DB_PostEig.Any(y => y.EigTwo == x.Two && y.EigA == authName) && x.ThrD == currentDate)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: 1) why in var eig and var data you have multiple instances of postone and posteig? Wouldn't it be just one each? 2) why have 'eigtwo' and 'two' in there? I don't see how they are relating to each other. Their value isn't determined until later...?? I'm a little lost on your solution, but it kind of makes sense

Comment: I don't have access to your database so I created a "fake" in memory database to hold some data that I could query. I have updated my naming conventions to hopefully help readability.